# Implement logic from JUnit tests

Tags: java

I lost some Java code. I keep only several JUnit tests for hashing. I tried to implement this:

```
public interface HmacService {
    String hash(final String number);

    String getCheckhash(final String hash);
}
...
class HmacServiceImpl implements HmacService {

    public String hash(String number) {
        try {
            return Hashing.sha256().hashString(plainCardNumber, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toString();
        } catch (Exception var3) {            
        }
    }

    public String getNonCreditCardSha1Hmac(String hash) {
        try {
          return Hashing.sha1().hashString(hash, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toString();
        } catch (Exception var3) {            
        }
    }


   final class HashPair{
        String firstHash;
        String secondHash;

        public HashPair(String firstHash, String secondHash) {
            this.firstHash = firstHash;
            this.secondHash = secondHash;
        }
        
        // perform hash comparison here
    }
}
```

JUnit tests:

```
public HmacService.HashPair generateQuickHash(final String cardNum) {
    return cryptoService.generateHashPair(cardNum);
}

if(new HmacService.HashPair(oldHash, oldHash)) == null){
// some error message
}
```

Do you know how I can implement the code based on the JUnit tests?

Comment: So ok, I guess I see one test...the `if` statement., right?  And I see from there that you define an object that will match up with the test.  That's good.  If you have a whole bunch of tests, I could see this method getting you back some amount of the entrypoint definitions (the API).  But that's as far as I see you being able to take this.  The unit tests would usually tell you almost nothing about the business logic, or how the code interacted with the outside world...with the net, with databases, with other services and APIs.  I don't see this being of much value.

Comment: As Gonzalo points out in his answer., if you have a lot of good tests, you're all set to start rewriting the code using Test Driven Development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is testing [HMAC-SHA-256](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4868) and there are countless Java implementations of it. The strange thing just is, that no signature is being passed - neither when hashing, nor when comparing the hashes. I don't think that the code has any real purpose alike this.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how strong your coverage of that part of the code was.

If it had high coverage, you can follow a [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) like approach doing Red-Green-Refactor cycles.

To start I would comment all failing tests but one (the simplest one) [first red] an then do the implementation to make it pass [first green].

Then uncomment the next test and implement again.

Rinse and repeat until all test are uncommented and passing.

Comment: Good work Gonzalo.  You managed to find a way to interpret this question such that it made some bit of sense (just barely).